# automatically get the href in <a> tag from the src of an <img> tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, lightbox

This probably seems like a strange question at first, but I haven't managed to find another way to solve the problem.  Apologies if this is long winded, but I wanted to try and explain exactly what I'm trying to do!

Basically, I am using lightbox to display an image which when clicked, enlarges the image (this being what lightbox does..!) This is working fine, however:
What lightbox *actually* does is load another image - useful so you can have two files, one small (thumbnail) and one large.  I could even put the same image in both locations and scale the small one using CSS/html - as I have here - the relevant piece of lightbox code is below:

```
<a href="image1.gif" rel="lightbox" title="Project one image">
<img  src="image1.gif" width="200px" alt="small version of image" /></a>
```

(I understand that it is preferable to have two seperate files for loading time etc, but in this case this will not work)

But the problem I am having is that the image in the image tag needs to be able to be changed (to a completely different image), *without* anything else been changed - so without updating the href for the lightbox link. But the lightbox needs to show the same image as is brought up by the image tag- as it stands, both the img  tag and a  tag need to be changed to do this.
In this case, it will not be possible to edit the a  tag - I am setting this up to allow another (fairly technophobic) person to replace the image using CushyCMS (a content editor) - this realistically only gives the ability to change the image itself, as I cannot rely on this person to also update the a  tag (this is definitely not an option!)

What I need to know is, is there a way to make the image referred to in the a  tag automatically be the same as that referred to in the img  tag, whatever this may be at the time?  From research so far I believe that jquery / javascript would be the solution here.
I've tried modifying some other javascript code that I've found, but possibly due to my own ineptitude I haven't been able to make it work.

If anyone has a solution, it would be greatly appreciated if they could also idiot-proof it for me, I've successfully used javascript that came complete with script tags, but beyond that I've had little success!

Thanks for your time reading and for any help anyone can offer!

Comment: So, the TL;DR version is to take the `img` `src` attribute and put it in the `a` `href` attribute?

Comment: I think the essenc of your solution might be here: `this realistically only gives the ability to change the image itself`. Can you save the new image with the filename of the old one?

Comment: Karl-Andre - pretty much, yeah, sorry :P

Mike - no, because of the way the content editor works, I'll have no control over the image name... if only I did life would be so much simpler!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am still confused by this question, but i think that's what you want. The `img` src attribute can change from the CMS but no the `a`. Try this to fix it :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var $a = $('a[rel=lightbox]');
    $a.each(function(){
        $(this).attr('href', $(this).find('img').attr('src'));
    })

})
```

Comment: Hi Karl - yes, that's right, only the img attribute can be changed.
The a tag will be straight before the img tag, as in the example.  I shouldn't need to put anything in between them.

I will have multiple images on some pages though, will this still work?

I'm afraid I really don't know much javascript at all, where would I / how would I put those pieces of script?  (sorry for the daft question :( )  

Thanks for your help!

Comment: the html is pretty much the same as I showed in my first post.  I've made an otherwise empty page to test this with, I've put the html for this page in pastebin - http://pastebin.com/PuK0RWgM (the html for my actual pages is quite long so I am testing seperately)

Comment: @RoxyWalsh, was looking to fast, didnt see the image tag was inside the `a` tag, use find instead of next (changed my answer). http://pastebin.com/dZv41HhH

Comment: Fantastic!  That works perfectly, thanks so much for your help!  :)
My editor can now change the images to her heart's content without me needing to change anything!  Thank you :)

Comment: I've just tried it out with two images on the page  - http://pastebin.com/N9v0z7hm - it woks well with one image, but with two, when the second image is clicked, it opens the large version of the first image, rather than of itself :-/

Comment: I'm back again - tried this out using lightbox sets (adding a set name in square brackets in the rel=lightbox tag) which allows you to scroll through a set of images - it isn't happy doing this with the javascript!  Do you think there is a way around or should I just not bother with sets (they're not essential!) http://pastebin.com/0zKwyUHN

Comment: Try using the start with selector : `$('a[rel^=lightbox]')`